# Android card flip animation on views, not fragments

Tags: android, android-animation

I've seen many examples for implementing a card flip animation when transitioning between two fragments, however I need to implement it on two views within a single fragment. Basically, within a listview row we have some property details.

[image]

They the user taps a more button in the lower right, I want to flip the row's view so it shows the actions for that row instead.

[image]

I have card_flip_left_in.xml, card_flip_left_out.xml, card_flip_right_in.xml, and card_flip_right_out.xml animations in my Resources/anim folder. I wasn't sure how to proceed beyond this.

Comment: Offtopic but why are you using a ListView?
This should work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296461/6525469.
You can swap the two duplicate image views in the abovementioned answer with yours.

Comment: There are multiple properties in a list.

Comment: You want animations on individual elements like `Create Report` `Call Agent` ...?

Comment: No, just the overall row view. So it'll flip between showing the property details view and showing the actions view.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296461/6525469